# Why doesn't this Python user-defined function do its task?

Tags: python, pandas, types, user-defined-functions

I created this function in Python to check the data type of each column of a DF and make sure it becomes the data type it's supposed to be.

```
def dataType(df):

    '''This function makes sure the data type for all 7 columns of the final dataframe are correct'''

    #Day as date type

    df["Day"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Day"])

    df["Day"] = df["Day"].dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")

    #Channel, Partner as string type

    df[["Channel", "Partner"]] = df[["Channel", "Partner"]].astype(str)

    #Spend, Clicks, Impressions, Platform Conversions as float type

    df['Platform Conversions'] = df['Platform Conversions'].where(df['Platform Conversions'] == "null", 0)

    df[["Spend", "Clicks", "Impressions", "Platform Conversions"]] = df[["Spend", "Clicks", "Impressions", "Platform Conversions"]].astype(float)

    return df
```

And I tested each column with a code like this but they all still output saying all columns are object type. What am I doing wrong?

```
print(df["Day"].dtypes)
```

Comment: Maybe you could try building a new df from scratch, adding columns (which will be astyped to their appropriate type) one at a time.

Comment: @MarkLavin, yes that's actually what I originally did. I'm attempting to do this (create a definition) because it would save at least 200 lines of code. So is there a way to create the desired function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html

```
df["Day"] = df["Day"].dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

does not return a datetime object.

I test the dt.strftime function (outside a function, which is equivalent):

> ```
> d = '''Day
> 01/01/2001
> 01/02/2001'''
> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d))
> df.dtypes
>
> Day    object
> dtype: object
> ```

> ```
> df["Day"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Day"])
> df.dtypes
>
> Day    datetime64[ns]
> dtype: object
> ```

> ```
> df["Day"] = df["Day"].dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
> df.dtypes
>
> Day    object
> dtype: object
> ```

Comment: @Claie Kindly check the 'tick' to accept the answer if it answers your question.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi @EBDS, so how would I do the same for the other columns to their designated types then (string and float type)?

Comment: @Claie What you did is correct in coverting to the respective type.  The issue here is you expected dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") to be a datetime but this operation returns a string.  That's why you see them as object.